# Any C++ libraries available to convert between floating point representations?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I recently had a need to interpret a DEC 32-bit floating point representation.  It differs from the IEEE floating point representations in the number of bits allocated to the exponent and mantissa.

Here's a description of a bunch of floating point formats:

http://www.quadibloc.com/comp/cp0201.htm

I managed to roll my own C++ code to stuff a DEC 32-bit float into an IEEE 32-bit float but was wondering if there were any libraries out there that had tackled this conversion and others already.

I checked [boost.org](http://www.boost.org) but didn't see any in there.

Comment: Good question!  I think I got reasonable numbers without actually knowing which format.  I'll figure it out and post another comment when I'm in front of my code again.

Comment: EvilTeach, it looks like it was dfloat (55 mantissa bits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like [libvaxdata](http://pubs.usgs.gov/of/2005/1424/)?

I've never used it - I just found it by googling.  But it looks like what you're looking for.

It's a C library rather than C++, but converting floating point data should work fine from extern "C" calls.

Answer (score 1):

Ha ... not sure why I didn't check Code Project:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/libnumber.aspx